# I am confused about the difference between 'n' and print('n')

Tags: python, string

I am still confused when entering this command in the Python shell:

```
>>> 'n'
'n'
>>> print('n')
n
```

What does `'n'` (first output) mean? And what does the other one `n` mean? Why doesn't Python just print `n` as output of `'n'` same as `print('n')` produced?

I think `print('n')` means:  *I (Python) print `n` as a character*

Then how about the first one? if `>>> 'n'` means the same, why doesn't it just print `n` as well?

Comment: I removed the references to colour; those depend on the exact shell you are using. IDLE will colour-code output, a standard terminal won't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running the python interpreter in [interactive mode](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode), which *echos* values back at you. Expressions are evaluated and if they return something other than `None`, the interpreter does the equivalent of:

```
print(repr(result))
```

That is the `'n'` you see printed.

`print()` on the other hand, writes directly to your terminal output, after converting the value to a string (the result of the `str()` function, but for a string value, there is no difference as it already *is* a string object).

This is different from running the Python code in a script; there there is no prompt, and if you put just `'n'` on one line, the Python interpreter would just ignore that line as it doesn't alter any state. `print('n')` on the other hand still would write the string to your console or terminal.

The interactive mode is there to help you figure out what python expressions *do*, and by using `repr()` you can distinguish between different types of objects. Try print `1` and `"1"`, so an integer number, and a string with the digit `1` in it:

```
>>> print(1)
1
>>> print("1")
1
```

You cannot tell the difference between these two. But their *representation* **does** differ:

```
>>> 1
1
>>> "1"
'1'
```

Representations for most Python standard types will use a notation that can be reused in your Python code, as-is.

Comment: Yes, I understand now, so 'n' is different with print('n'), 'n' as input means Python prints echo value, it will prints what we input 'literally', and print('n') prints n as a character.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply echoing your input (a string).  When you `print` n, it's outputting the value of your string.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to put this is in a .py file and execute it from the command line, then `print('n')` would print something, but just `'n'` inside a file does nothing.

The interactive prompt is slightly confusing because if the expression you wrote has a value other than None, its representation is printed. So that's why `'n'` prints `'n'` in that case. But that is something the interactive prompt does, not what the codes does.

Answer (score 0):

you should first understand everything in python are OBJECT. which means 'n' is a object, and when `print` it you calls a function of object 'n'.(`OBJECT.__str__()`).

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self,name,ge,age):
         self.ge = ge
         self.age = age
         self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
         print "This is",self.name
         print "age = ",self.age
         print "gender = ".self.ge

boy = Human("Tom", "M", 12)
print boy
```